how to fix unmet dependencies?
@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager gnome-tweaks git curl wget sassc htop neofetch -y

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
wget is already the newest version (1.21.4-1ubuntu4).
wget set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl4t64 (= 8.5.0-2ubuntu10) but 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


Update your software lists; ie. sudo apt update as your details show an non-updated system (ie. libcurl4t64 | 8.5.0-2ubuntu10   | noble refers to package found on install media; and libcurl4t64 | 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.1 | noble-updates matches updates...  You've either not updated your system OR have installed a 3rd party package that has created problems (which you've forced via -y usage but not corrected)
